# Value of limsup i?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

This is a part of my question.

$\lim \sup \cos(n\pi/12)$ as n goes to infinity

What is the value of this limit?

Comment: This is equal to zero ? @julien

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a sequence is bounded, the limsup is the largest limit of all convergent subsequences.

For all $n$, $\cos(n\pi/2)\leq 1$ so $\limsup\cos(n\pi/2) \leq 1$.

And for the extraction $n=4k$, $\cos(n\pi/2)=\cos(2k\pi)=1$. So $\limsup\cos(n\pi/2)\geq 1$.

Hence
$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\cos(n\pi/2)=1.
$$